# How to get precise location on clicking of a button

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add a transparent button on map and get precise location when click on this button. I also want to open a dialog on Long tap of a map. I am using a seprate customized overlay class to implement a map. like

```
public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {


        RelativeLayout mainRelativeLayout;
        ScrollView scroll;

.
.
.

 @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
       {   
    //     Log.i("onTouch()", "Performed on map");
           if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
               GeoPoint geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                   (int) event.getX(),
                   (int) event.getY());
               // latitude
               double lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
               // longitude
               double lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;

.
.
.
           Pick_Drop_Dialog p_dialog = new Pick_Drop_Dialog(context,mapView);
           p_dialog.showDialog().show();

}
}
```

here I get this dialog onTouch() event of mapview, but I need to get this dialog on LongTap of the map (Note: onLongTap of map, noy an icon)Please help me

Comment: i guess its android google map v1, right? or its v2?

Comment: I m using a key, which I create before December 2012, so it must be API v1, because v2 comes in December 2012. what is the solution for, is this the reason not to achieve this?

Comment: Now I m using API v2 map key? I change my v1 =--> v2

Comment: the reason i asked because, while i used to code for v1, there was such codes like the one you posted, but for v2, such codes aren't necessary. the code for v2 is much concise and healthy

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem correctly based on the comments, I guess you should have a look at [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener).

For Android Google Maps v2, I think you can follow this [tutorial](http://droidtraining.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/day-13-how-to-integrate-google-maps-in-an-android-application-api-v2/). This tutorial is concise and to the point. Please have a glimpse at part 3 of this tutorial, you will see that overlays may seem redundant in v2.

I guess the next bigger problem will be generating the API key, for that please go through this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IaXE2FUENFI). So far the best of what I have seen.

**Please note that, in v2, you can't see the map in the emulator, you will need a real device to see the map.**

Comment: try this:                                                                   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {                      long longPressTime = event.getEventTime();
 }                                                                                                 else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
  {
    longPressTime = event.getEventTime() - longPressTime;
    if (longPressTime>2000) // 2 seconds
            { // Do whatever}                                       }

Comment: @Maddy did that solve your problem? if yes then please add your answer to an answer field and accept the same.

Comment: I have an application created in android 2.2 version and using google maps api v1. Now I want to use gmap api v2, is this possible?